# "Undefined function" when using a function in a join?

Tags: ms-access, ms-access-2013

I'm getting an irritating issue on a join and I was wondering if there is a way around it.

```
RIGHT JOIN TableB B ON B.Field1 = A.Field1 AND Str(B.Field2) = A.Field2
```

For some reason, putting Str() in the join throws an "Undefined function 'Str' in expression"

Yet if I don't do this, I get a type mismatch.  Very frustrating.  Any workarounds short of changing the data type in my column?

Comment: Does CStr() work instead?

Comment: This can be caused by a compile error or a library/reference error in your VBA. See here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30861380/access-built-in-functions-like-year-and-date-are-not-recognized

Comment: For a sanity check, what happens when you omit `Str()` from the `JOIN` clause but include in elsewhere in the query e.g. in the `WHERE` clause?