# Access design view causing the expression to not be recognized

Tags: ms-access

`Writing this in guided mode was kind of awkward without the titles for each segment, here goes..`

**Summarize the problem:**
If the dateAdd expression is written in design view it returns:
`The expression you entered contains invalid syntax.
 You may have entered an operand without and operator`

**Provide background and tell us what you've already tried:**
This is a new access document just to test this and the result was the same.

I have a table and query. The table contains one row with three columns.
The query updates one of the table columns with a dateadd expression.

**Show your code:**
    `DateAdd("m",4,Now()`

**Describe expected and actual results:**
It should accept the expression as is but returns an error if it's written in design view. 
**If it is written in SQL view and then changed over to design view** the expression works.

**Pictures:**

Here's the design view from the query, with the expression and error message:
[image]

Here I've changed to SQL view and added the same expression:
[image]

And lastly I've changed back from SQL view to design view and now I don't get the error from the expression until I try and edit it again from this view.
[image]

*Can anyone tell me why this is happening or is it just a bug in MS Access?

Is this only happening for dateAdd specifically?*

Edit:
As seen here, the VBA library works fine, it's **only** in design view that I get an issue.
[image]

Comment: Program may be corrupted, just do a compact and repair

Comment: Could be a MISSING reference. Go to menu _Tools, References_ and check.

Comment: @S.Jose FYI, This is a completely new access document. I tried to do a compact and repair, nothing changed.

Comment: @Gustav In the vba window _View_ -> _Object Browser_ I find dateadd in the VBA Library. In the path you described **Visual Basic For Applications** is enabled

Comment: It should work. Try creating a new database and recreate the query.

Comment: @Gustav I had this problem in my main database, so I created this database specifically to test this in a fresh environment. Is it really necessary to recreate it again?

Comment: @Gustav the worst part of this problem is that if I create a macro (not vba, but with the macro editor) that contains an if block with i.e DateAdd I get this error as well. So to bypass the error I have to run a query with the contents of the if block,  and then write an expression that checks the result inside the if block.

Answer (score 0):

You could follow these steps to refresh the VBA references [Access built-in functions like Year() and Date() are not recognized](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30861380/access-built-in-functions-like-year-and-date-are-not-recognized)

If that doesn't work, you can use the other alternative function `Date()` which gives you only the current date component. `Now()` gives you both the current date and time.

You can also workaround the issue by creating a function in a module to get the value of `Now()` and use this custom function in your queries.

```
Public Function GetNow() As Date
    GetNow = Now()
End Function
```

Also check if you have any controls, fields or other objects called `Now` in your database.

If you believe the issue is with the `DateAdd` function, then you can build a workaround function for that:

```
Public Function DoDateAdd(Interval As String, Number As Integer, InputDate As Date) As Date
    DoDateAdd = DateAdd(Interval, Number, InputDate)
End Function
```

Comment: The problem lies with the editor itself. I can execute dateAdd, I just can't write it **i̲n̲_̲t̲h̲e̲_̲d̲e̲s̲i̲g̲n̲_̲v̲i̲e̲w̲**. As I commented above to Gustav however is that ***the workaround to use SQL view to write the expression doesn't work everywhere***, for instance in the macro editor with a IF block there is not SQL view. Yes, I know how to work around the problem (using SQL view or for if blocks; I execute the code that doesn't work from a query and then use the IF block to looks at the result from the query which is either true or false), my question is why I can't use design view..

Comment: Probably some configuration issue with the workstation. Try repairing your Office installation.